# Compare 2 CSV's Record fields values added,deleted, modified

Tags: python, r

Would like help to compare 2 csv's files, spot differences and record fields added/deleted/modified in latest csv files

I have tried multiple packages but won't get better results and I think manual coding will help find fields added/deleted/modified in current file compared to previous. I have tried this in R but I am open to python assistance too

```
library(readr)
library(daff)
library(dplyr)

setwd("path")

# Load csvs to compare into data frames
x_original <- read.csv("CN_DD.csv")
x_changed <- read.csv("CN_DD_rev5.csv")

originaldf <- tbl_df(x_original)
changeddf<- tbl_df(x_changed)

#Get shared items
inner_join(originaldf, changeddf)

#to get non shared items
anti_join(originaldf, changeddf)
```

End result should be another generated csv with information on fields added, deleted and modified